# JSF commandLink onclick EL expression re-evaluation

Tags: jsf, commandlink

I have a JSF command like this:

```
<h:commandLink id="testId" onclick="if (#{bean.isPageOpen}) dlg.show();" />
```

The boolean bean.isPageOpen was false initially so the dlg widget was not opened. Now when I change the condition i.e. bean.isPageOpen returns true, the widget still does not get open.

Is the EL expression evaluated only once and never again for JSF commandLink?

Thanks,
-csn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript codes  is producing on page load. If you check your page source , You can see your onclick like this.

```
 onclick="if (false) dlg.show();"
```

If you want to use updated value in your bean.You might use structure like this.I'm using primefaces.

```
<p:inputText id="textId" value="#{{bean.isPageOpen}" />
<h:commandLink id="testId" onclick="refresh(); if (document.getElementById('textId').value=='true') dlg.show();" />
<p:remoteCommand name="refresh" actionListener="#{bean.updateisPageOpen}" update ="textId"/>
```